# mysql performance limit X or Limit 0,X

Tags: mysql

From following  which is better

```
select * , 98 as match_score from table_name order by match_score desc  limit Y
```

or

```
select *, 98 as match_score  from table_name  order by match_score desc limit 0,Y
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT Y` is short for `LIMIT 0,Y` so I don't see any scope for gain in performance.

Comment: thanks for reply. Yes, both are same but which one is better?

Comment: `LIMIT Y` is two characters short compared to `LIMIT 0,Y`, so if you value your time a lot, I suggest you use `LIMIT Y`.